# Vue-router: router-view tag is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, url-routing

I am new to Vue, and I'm trying to use vue-router for one of my projects but `router-view` is not working.

**This is a part of App.vue:**

```
<template>
<div>
  <the-navbar></the-navbar>
</div>
<main>
  <router-view></router-view>  
</main>
</template>
```

**This is my router.js file:**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import HomePage from './components/HomePage.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {path: '/home', component: HomePage},
  ]
})

export default router;
```

**This is my main.js file:**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import App from './App.vue' ;
import router from './router.js';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(bootstrap);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: start by changing `/home` to `/` then try to access it

Comment: I tried and it's still not working

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: what does "not working" actually mean?  is it an error? blank screen? unexpected result? please fully explain what you want to have happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: it's not showing anything, sorry if it's unclear

Comment: @Angelina no errors or anything at the console

Comment: @Virist, can you, please, provide a link to the repo of this project on GitHub, since I didn't see any mistake in the represented code. By the way, when I tried to use my frontend framework like you did (with the help of `app.use()`, i.e. `app.use(bootstrap)`), I've got a warning saying `A plugin must either be a function or an object with an "install" function.` I use Materialize, so, from my experience, `import 'materialize-css'` is enough. Also, do you have a v-if condition in `HomePage` component? If yes, maybe it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Angelina I fixed my problem already, I found out that there's an error when I install the vue router, re-installing the package fixed the issue, thanks for the help, also thanks to Damzaky and Yoduh for helping me

Comment: @Virist, I'm so glad for you! When using Materialize, please, bear in mind that `import 'materialize-css'` only imports JS, you still need to import CSS. To do this, I insert `@import '../../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';` at the beginning of `app.scss` Have a nice trip!

Comment: What is the file and file path of component: HomePage?

Comment: hi @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ, in case you're still wondering, the problem have been solved in the comments above sorry for not responding for a long time as I am not very active on this platform

Comment: @Angelina thanks for the help! and yes, I will do keep in mind about materialize and other necessary stuff